# Is it OK to reuse tag wiki descriptions across Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-wiki

Certain tags are common to more than one Stack Exchange sites and the context is similar enough for these sites to share a common description of the tag (or at least significant portions of the description).

Stack Overflow and Programmers are good examples.

If a tag wiki is missing on a site, is it OK to copy the description of a corresponding tag from a different site?

By asking that, I assume that the copied descriptions (or relevant parts thereof) would each have a line of attribution (crediting the whole community of the other site as opposed to specific users who have ever edited the original tag wiki). I also limit this question to situations, in which homonymous tags do actually share a meaning and the original description remains valid in the new context (which is to be decided by the approvers of a tag wiki edit on the target site anyway)

Are there any other considerations to be made?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote that appeared on the question. IMHO it's not a bad thing to consider, and on the other hand, it's not clear whether this is welcome or not.

Comment: @yo' my thoughts exactly. Downvotes are perfectly fine as long as they are a way to voice disapproval in the discussion I wanted to start. A comment/answer from the downvoter would be welcome though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could argue that the same tag on different sites will have the same meaning on all those sites, but that might not be the case.

On related sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc, for example) the same term would apply to on-topic questions, but the emphasis will be different for the different audiences.

On completely unrelated sites it could be that the same word has completely different meanings.

So, while using the tag wiki from one site on another may appear to be a good idea, it's not something you should just copy and paste. You should make sure that the tag does in fact refer to the same thing on both sites and, even if it does, tailor the wiki to each site's audience.

Comment: Indeed, copying tags blindly never crossed my mind. It's just that some decent and on-topic research has been done on some of the tags and large portions, if not all of the content may be perfectly applicable to both sites and their respective audiences.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. +1